# Enter Key on ASPX Framework 2

Tags: asp.net, textbox, keyboard

I have this text box on my site:

```
<asp:TextBox id="txtboxStream" Wrap="True" runat="server" Font-Size="11px" Height="231px" ForeColor="#000000" Width="520px" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
```

but i can not use the "enter key". My framework is very old (Framework 2.0).

I want use the enter key to simple and normal line-break

Answer (score 0):

set the rows and columns property and see.

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtboxStream" TextMode="MultiLine" Columns="50"
       Rows="5" runat="server"/>
```

Comment: the enter key not work, but i get some result. thanks

Comment: have you written some jquery or java-scriipt which is stooping the enter key on your textbox.

Comment: nop, i don't have any javascript or jquery on this page. i thinks this is problem  of this framework

Answer (score 0):

I need add a JavaScript function:

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
                                            function runScript(e) {
                                                if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                                                var text = document.getElementById( "ConteudoHtmlID" ).value;

                                                document.getElementById( "ConteudoHtmlID" ).value = text +  '\n';


                                                }                                                   
                                            }
                                            </SCRIPT>
```